# multiple argument values error

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, oop

I'm just starting out in OOP for python (so please excuse me if this is a stupid question). I am working with a model which uses a function to simulate the decay of a CO2 emission within the atmosphere. For each timestep, the `c_size` property of the class `Emission` should decrease using the `decay` function

I've simplified the code to a single run, but I keep getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<co2>", line 20, in <module>
x.decay(year=1) 
TypeError: decay() got multiple values for argument 'year'
```

I can't see where any multiple values could be coming from. I'm only passing a single `int` value to the code.

The code is:

```
import numpy as np

class Emission:
    def __init__(self,e_year=0, e_size=0.0):
        self.e_year=e_year #emission year
        self.e_size=e_size #emission size
        self.c_size=[e_size] #current size

    def decay(year):
        #returns a % decay based on the year since emission 0 = 100% 1 = 93%
        # etc. from AR5 WG1 Chapter 8 supplementary material equation 8.SM.10
        # using coefficients from table 8.SM.10
        term1 = 0.2173
        term2 = 0.224*np.exp(-year/394.4)
        term3 = 0.2824*np.exp(-year/36.54)
        term4 = 0.2763*np.exp(-year/4.304)
        out = (term1+term2+term3+term4)*self.e_size
        self.c_size.append(out)
        print(self.c_size)

x = Emission(e_year=1,e_size=10.0)
x.decay(year=1)
```

Comment: FWIW, once you add `self` to the method signature of `Emission.decay`, your code prints `[10.0, 9.3452514335147363]`. You may be wondering why Python doesn't give a more helpful error message here. Well, it can't - there's nothing special about the name `self`, it's just a conventional name used to refer to the instance, and Python allows you to name it anything you want.

Comment: thanks - that's what I was expecting. it's still WIP, but I'll need to be able to show the history of each object as it decays over time - hence the need for a list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot the `self` in the method signature for `decay` so Python tried to insert the instance as first argument (which is `year`) and you also passed in `year` explicitly - resulting in the conflict of arguments.

So just change the method definition to:

```
def decay(self, year):
```

---

It's important to realize that the name `self` for the first argument of methods is just a convention. It also works if you name it `year` (although you have to find a different name for the second argument), or `this` or `the_instance`. The important thing is that the instance is implicitly passed as first argument to the method when you call the method.

So this would work as well:

```
def decay(blabla, year):
    term1 = 0.2173
    term2 = 0.224*np.exp(-year/394.4)
    term3 = 0.2824*np.exp(-year/36.54)
    term4 = 0.2763*np.exp(-year/4.304)
    out = (term1+term2+term3+term4)*blabla.e_size
    blabla.c_size.append(out)
    print(blabla.c_size)
```

But that's against the common Python convention and I had to change all the `self`s in the method with `blabla`.

---

Further comments:

In case you're exclusively dealing with scalars as `year` you probably should use `math.exp` instead of `numpy.exp`, because it's much faster. But `math.exp` only works on scalars, so if you want to use lists or arrays for `year` you have to use `numpy.exp`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I appreciate the lack of mockery for a very simple question :)

Comment: @WillRolls Yes, it is pretty simple, but we've all done it at one time or another, even those of us with lots of OOP experience.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument of class methods should be self.

```
class Emission:
    def __init__(self,e_year=0, e_size=0.0):
        self.e_year=e_year #emission year
        self.e_size=e_size #emission size
        self.c_size=[e_size] #current size

    def decay(self, year):
        #returns a % decay based on the year since emission 0 = 100% 1 = 93% etc. from AR5 WG1 Chapter 8 supplementary material equation 8.SM.10 using coefficients from table 8.SM.10
        term1 = 0.2173
        term2 = 0.224*np.exp(-year/394.4)
        term3 = 0.2824*np.exp(-year/36.54)
        term4 = 0.2763*np.exp(-year/4.304)
        out = (term1+term2+term3+term4)*self.e_size
        self.c_size.append(out)
        print(self.c_size)
```

Comment: Thanks, I assumed it'd be something pretty simple (for people who know what they are doing...)